# Baire space and Topological property

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Show that the property of being a Baire space is a topological property.

> **Baire space**: In mathematics, a topological space $X$ is said to be a Baire space, if for any given countable collection $\{A_n\}$  of
> closed sets with empty interior in $X$, their union $∪_{n\in\Bbb N} A_n$ also has
> empty interior in $X$
>
> **Topological property**:  a property of spaces is a topological property if whenever a space $X$ possesses that property every space
> homeomorphic to $X$ possesses that property
> **Edit**:

Assume $X$ is a Baire space and let f be a homeomorphism map from $X$ to $Y$ this mean that $f$ is continuous, $1-1$, onto, open and closed map which the last one is equivalent to the inverse of this map is continuous what is the aim? the aim is to show that Y is Baire space so let $\{A_n\}$  be a countable collection of closed sets with empty interior in $Y$ show that  their union $∪_{n\in\Bbb N} A_n$ also has empty interior in $Y$ ,since for any $n∈\Bbb N$  the set $A_n$ is closed set in $Y$ and since $f$ is continuous map then $\{f^{-1}[A_n]\}$  is a countable collection of closed sets in $X$ , my first question is if $\operatorname{int} (A_n) = ∅$  then $f^{-1}[\operatorname{int}(A_n)] = \operatorname{int}(f^{-1}[A_n]) =  ∅$  ? if we assume that is true then since the $X$ is Baire space the union
$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}f^{-1}[A_n]$  also has empty interior in $X$ , my second question is if $\operatorname{int }(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} f^{-1}[A_n ]) = ∅$ then $f(\operatorname{int}(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}f^{-1}[A_n])=\operatorname{int}(A_n )= ∅$
if this is true then Y is a Baire space
İs my solution true and can anyone help me to answer my question and explain it thank you
Note: i know it not nice to write in this way on the site but i don't know how i can write on the site therefore i use word to write on

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Prove that for any continuous map $g \colon X \to Y$, and any $B \subseteq Y$, one has that $g^{-1}(\operatorname{Int}(B)) \subseteq \operatorname{Int}(g^{-1}(B))$. Show that the reverse inclusion holds if $g$ is open. Once you do this, your proof is correct.

Comment: and what about my second question , i proved one side if f is open map then f (İnt A ) subset of int (f(A)) what about the other side